Understanding branching of Lie algebra representation
I want to understand the Sp($2n, \mathbb{C}$)-representation $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 \Gamma_{0,0,1}$ as a $\text{SL}(n, $\mathbb{C})$ representation, where SL$(n, $\mathbb{C}) \subset$ Sp($2n, \mathbb{C}$) acts by $V \oplus V^*$, where $V$ is the standard representation and $V^*$ is its dual.
It was my understanding that $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_n^*) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_4 \wedge e_n^*)$ is a highest weight vector for the irreducible SL representation $\Phi_{0,0,0,1,0,...,0,2}$. But when I branch $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 \Gamma_{0,0,1}$ with LiE, $\Phi_{0,0,0,1,0,...,0,2}$ is not part of the direct sum decomposition. Why not?
Alternatively (but similarly!), $\Phi_{0,0,1,0,...,0,1,1}$ is in the direct sum decomposition and I thought that had highest weight vector $(e_1 \wedge e_{n-1}^* \wedge e_n^*) \wedge (e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_n^*)$.

On a formatting note the $\operatorname{Sp}$ and $\operatorname{SL}$ should go within the dollar signs rather than trying to render them as text. I would probably put them in \operatorname{} for best results. So, for example, \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C}) becomes $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$. This would also fix the mismatched sizes of the brackets.

There seems to be some confusion here. You write $\Gamma_{0,0,1}$ but seem to be basing things from the defining representation of $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ and, assuming you are pulling the notation from Fulton and Harris, those aren't the same thing. I think this is a mix-up with the fact that $\Gamma_{0,0,1,\dots}$ can be viewed inside $\bigwedge^3\Gamma_{1,0,0,\dots}$. So I will assume we are working in $\bigwedge^2\bigwedge^3\Gamma_{1,0,0,\dots}$
Next I think your proposed highest weight vector is not of highest weight. I'm assuming from context that $e_1$ and $e_n^*$ are highest weight vectors of $V$ and $V^*$ respectively and the others following in the obvious order. Then $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_n^*) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_4 \wedge e_n^*)$ can be raised to $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_n^*) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_4 \wedge e_n^*)$ for example. I think the natural highest weight vector there would be $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_n^*) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_n^*)$ instead.
I'm not really sure what you are asking for the second part. That again doesn't look like a highest weight vector but there can be other vectors with the same weight that could be instead.
